# SSH attempts not logging in /var/log/

Tags: ssh, sshd

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 server with a hostnames 'example.org' and 'sub.domain.com', and some IP x.x.x.x, and with `fail2ban` installed.

On one client computer, I can SSH into my server at user@example.org, user@sub.domain.com, and user@x.x.x.x. On another client however, I cannot SSH into user@example.org.

Furthermore, upon digging into the server `/var/log/` files, there are no logs for the second client attempting to log in via user@example.org. This is also evident in that `fail2ban` does not ban the second client upon multiple failed password attempts at user@example.org.

Running `ssh -vvv user@example.org` on the second client, the last debug message just says that the client is talking to the server - and then is denied.

Is there any way for me to further debug the issue on the server, or something that I'm missing?

Edit: I should also note that the hostname is resolving properly on all machines - `ping`, `nslookup`, and `wget` all appear to work correctly when attempting to resolve example.org.

Answer (score 0):

For easier debugging, set the LogLevel directive in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to Verbose or Debug (it's Info by default)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the real problem is because you are obfuscating the error messages.
They are informative, familiar and less ambiguous than your renditions / interpretations. If you have error messages, provide them when requesting support.

The difference, I take it, lies in where these client machines are located relative to the server. I'm guessing one is *inside*, while the other is on the *outside*.

The error ' - and then is denied.' means that the server is not listening on that port. That is to say, the requested TCP port is not bound to a listening socket on the requested interface (IP address). Alternatively it means - client can not reach requested port on x.x.x.x due to a firewall.

You have to:

a. Allow connections originating from the *external interface* to reach TCP port 22

- iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT

b. Configure sshd to listen on all interfaces (default) or on the ip of the external interface.

- ListenAddress x.x.x.x (/etc/sshd/sshd_config)

If the external interface of your sshd host has a different IP address than what example.org resolves to, thek you have a NAT.

c. Set up Masquerading (NAT) on your router.

```
INTERNAL_IP=10.3.0.7
INTERNAL_NM=255.255.255.224
INTERNAL=eth0
EXTERNAL=wlan0

ifconfig $INTERNAL $INTERNAL_IP netmask $INTERNAL_NM up

echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTERNAL -s 10.3.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i $EXTERNAL -o $INTERNAL -m state \
                                   --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $INTERNAL -o $EXTERNAL -j ACCEPT

# -m state is deprecated these days so you should probably figure out what the 
# new NAT method is
```

To get a proper answer, try updating your questions with:

- real error messages
- real addresses
- is x x x x = 10.x.x.x or 192.x.x.x ?
- is x.x.x.x the address of the interface where sshd is listening? *(no need to disclose your full addresses, just hint at the subnets)*
- how do you obtain "properly resolved hostname"?
- where are your clients (IP)?

ref: [Ubuntu iptables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo)